# Meaning of "as well as"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[Essential Manners for Men 2nd Ed: What to Do, When to Do It, and Why](https://books.google.jo/books?id=K5fL67ckAjwC&pg=PT2&dq=%E2%80%9CShe%20knows%20and%20lives%20by%20what%20etiquette%20is%20as%20well%20as%20any%20person%20I%20know.%E2%80%9D&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr8f7L_uPYAhUFPFAKHfbWCNgQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CShe%20knows%20and%20lives%20by%20what%20etiquette%20is%20as%20well%20as%20any%20person%20I%20know.%E2%80%9D&f=false)

What is the meaning of the following sentence?

> She knows and lives by what etiquette is **as well as** any person I know.

In the above statement is the author saying that

- all the people he knows including *she* (his wife) know etiquette
- his wife knows etiquette equally well as others/ not only others that I know but my wife also knows etiquette

the first meaning is that the author knows only the people that know etiquette, the second meaning is derogatory for his wife.

EDIT: The above sentence is from Essentail Manners for Men by Peter Post, page 5 as follows:

For thirty years we have lived together, shared children, owned
a business together, gone shopping every week together, 
renovated one house and built another together. She introduced
me to two of the passions of my life: Italy and yoga. She knows
and lives by what etiquette is as well as any person I know. 
Certainly she has corrected me more than a few times, and, as
much as I hate to say it, she was almost always right-
Throughout this book she is referred to as "my wife."

Comment: Source of quote please.

Comment: @SovereignSun, Essential manners for men - Peter Post, page 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the second interpretation is correct, but it is not at all derogatory. The reason is that, when used in this way, **as X as** means **as X as the X-est**.

Here is another example: both examples mean the same thing, but the second is clearer.

> She is as clever as anyone I know.
>   She is as clever as the cleverest person I know.

Assuming that I know at least one person that is quite clever, that means that she also is quite clever.